# get Value that does not exist in another table and vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two table named `lu_timepoint` which holds default timepoints and another operational table called `tbl_data`.
The `tbl_data` contains details about a candidate and a timepoint when he has to come for lab test. The timepoint will range from -30 mins to 24 hrs

The `lu_timepoint` table is the lookup table for the default timepoints. 
I need to write a query that will check whether the timepoint in `tbl_data` exist in the `lu_timepoint` table and if its not there i need have the value as false in a column called checked.
Likewise if the timepoint in the lu_timepoint table does not exist in the `tbl_data` table i need have the value as false in the column checked. else true in a checked column.

I tried with Left Join however i'm getting more rows count due to incorrect join statement. 
below is the code i used to get all the candidate id whose timepoint is not equal to the other table

```
   select  distinct PT, PCTPT 
    from tbl_data s 
    left join lu_Timepoint t 
    on s.STUDY = t.Study 
    where s.PCTPT = t.Timepoint
```

Data is attached in the below link...
[Table Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uiwzl9u59nuxt7e/sample.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Provide which RDBMS (MySQL, Postegre, SQL-Server) are you using, sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your table structure?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas- I am using SQL 2012

Comment: @kaonashi I have uploaded the data in dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for this. I did a left join with the lu_timepoint table and tbl_data and got the values that does not exist in both the tables.

Below is the query i used.

```
select Candidate, CPEVENT, Test_Number, DosedTime, DoseTime, ExpectedTime, s.Timepoint as tmpt, t.Timepoint as tmpt1, CASE WHEN t.Timepoint IS NULL THEN 'Not Collected' WHEN s.timepoint IS NULL THEN 'Not Collected' ELSE 'Collected' END as Timepoint_Collection, case when t.timepoint is null THEN s.timepoint WHEN s.timepoint IS NULL THEN t.Timepoint WHEN s.timepoint = t.TIMEPOINT THEN s.timepoint END as Timepoint  from vw_data s FULL OUTER JOIN lu_pk_Timepoint t on s.PCTPT = t.Timepoint AND s.STUDY=t.Study
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the records that doesn't exists in the joined tabled and vice versa, you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` that display the distinct values from each table.

Specifying the database you are using and providing the tables structures and some of your data will help to build the final query.